# Terminal not recognizing vim as a command, batch file etc

Tags: windows, vim

So I was watching a tutorial on laravel and the tutor in the vid enters the command on the terminal as shown in the picture. He said we can use touch command on mac but to keep compatible on windows he's using vim. I don't believe he has vim.exe on his laravel project folder. Project name is freecodeGram as in pic. How do i get my computer to understand the vim command. Thanks in advance, I'm on windows.
Command was: `vim database/database.sqlite`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not use an image to convey information essential to the question. If the link breaks your question will not make any sense. Please see "[Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/128421)" and
"[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)", and "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
and "[Writing The Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)"

Comment: Will keep that in mind thank you. Thats why i was also included the command itself and gave a description

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454769/what-is-the-reason-for-x-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+is+not+recognized

Comment: Please don't keep it in mind, fix it now. While you might want your question to pertain to you only, SO wants it to be toward the future.

Comment: I just saw this comment pic deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the path to vim.exe to your system PATH. This would allow you to type vim ..... in the CLI and would execute vim directly. Otherwise, prefix vim database/database.sqlite with c:/path/to/vim database/database.sqlite

Comment: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml has a list of how-to’s for different versions of windows to add to your a variable to your PATH

Comment: I added vim exe to system path, but still vim is not recognized command?